# Primitive rings with the property $a(ab-ba)=(ab-ba)a$ for all $a,b\in R$ are division rings.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Suppose that $R$ is a primitive ring and for all $a,b\in R$ $$a(ab-ba)=(ab-ba)a.$$ 
>   Prove that $R$ is a division ring.

I know that I should use Jacobson density theorem, it is the hint of the problem.

Because $R$ is primitive so there is a simple $R$-module $M$ that $Ann_{R}\left ( M \right )= \left \{ 0 \right \}$.

By Schur's lemma $End_{R}\left ( M \right )= D$ is a division ring.

My plan is to show that any $r\in R$ has inverse. Because $R\subseteq End_{R}\left ( M \right )$, so I consider $r\in R$ as an endomorphism. So I decided to show that any $r\in R$ is both epimorphism and monomorphism. The kernel of any $r\in R$ is $\left \{ 0 \right \}$ because $\left \{ r:rM=0 \right \}=0$ (the $R$ is primitive), so any $r\in R$ is monomorphism.

Now I dont know how should I use the hypothsis to show that any $r\in R$ is epimorphism.

Also I am not sure that my plan will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try prove that $\dim_DM=1$.

Assume the contrary: there exist $x_1,x_2\in M$ linearly independent over $D$. Now apply the Jacobson Density Theorem and find $a_1,a_2\in R$ such that

> $a_1x_1=x_1$, $a_1x_2=0$, $a_2x_1=0$, $a_2x_2=x_1$.

Now use the given relation for $R$ to reach a contradiction.

Comment: thanks a lot,when you prove that $dim_{D}V=1$,actually you prove that any $r$ is epimorphism,can you explain me why it is true?

Comment: that was great solution,thank you.

Comment: I think that you mean a1x1=x1 , a1x2=0, a2x1=x2, a2x2=x1 because a1x1=x1 , a1x2=0, a2x1=0, a2x2=x1 gives only 0=a1(a1a2-a2a1)x1= (a1a2-a2a1)a1x1=0 which makes no contradiction but a1x1=x1 , a1x2=0, a2x1=0, a2x2=x1 gives 0=a1(a1a2-a2a1)x1= (a1a2-a2a1)a1x1=-x2 which contradicts for x2 is not zero. Am I right?